# Create Product programatically for guest resulting blank page

Tags: magento-1.9

we have below code and its creating new Product once registered user click on button **"create"**

```
_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >Create</button>' +

                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },
```

we are trying to apply if else conditions and adding below code for creating new product after guest click on "create" button and login to site. but it showing blank page

```
<script>

<?php if($customerId){?>

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >Create</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

<?php }else{?>

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button onclick=" setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >Create</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

    <?php }?>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing below code :

```
onclick="setproductlogin('<?php echo $_product->getEntityId()?>');setrequestlogin();"
```

by below code solved issue :

```
onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"
```